# Updating table row if clients email exists mvc asp.net optimisticConcurrencyException

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, code-first

Good evening, what i want to do is to create a form where you can register clients. But if the email already exists in the database then it has to update other client data for the same email such as firstname, lastname etc.

What i´ve done so far :

First returning true or false depending if the record is existing

```
public bool checkForExistingEmail(User user)
    {            
        var res = (from c in db.Users
                   where c.Email == user.Email
                   select c).SingleOrDefault();
        if (res == null)
        {

            return false;
        }
        else {
            return true;
        }
```

Here in the create method im tyring to update the users data according to email, but appearently it doesnt work and i get. `Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected number of rows (0). Entities may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded. Refresh ObjectStateManager entries.`

```
public ActionResult Create(User user)
    {


        if (ModelState.IsValid && checkForExistingEmail(user) == false)
        {

            db.Users.Add(user);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        else if (checkForExistingEmail(user) == true)
        {

            db.Entry(user).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");

        }
        return View(user);
    }
```

Note : 
I´ve also added the hidden @Razor element `@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.UserId)`in my Create.cshtml file.

Comment: what happens when you step thru the existing code..? are you getting more than one row returned when you try to execute Said Actions...?

Comment: Yeah more than one, i get the exception when i try to register existing email but with other firstname and lastname

Comment: sounds like your initial issue / problem lies within your `linq query` if this is not the case then your logic in regards to how you are updating the Entity Objects needs to definitely change returning True / False doesn't really help your case in your existing code..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming Entity framework:

Rather than manually setting `EntityState.Modified`, I personally would probably do something like this.

```
public ActionResult Create(User user)
{
    var res = (from c in db.Users
               where c.Email == user.Email
               select c).SingleOrDefault();

    if(res == null)
    {
        db.Users.Add(user);
    }
    else
    {
        res.Prop1 = user.Prop1
        res.Prop2 = user.Prop2
        ...
    }
    db.SaveChanges();
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```